# Blank Browser page is getting displayed in the Badboy Software. Can any one help me out to solve this?

Tags: jmeter, badboy

[image]

I'm getting  blank browser page in the Badboy to record the JMeter script. can anyone help me out to find out what will be the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using Badboy for recording a JMeter test because:

- https://www.badboy.com.au website doesn't even open
- the latest Badboy release is dated 2011 year which means JMeter 2.5.1 or lower and [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)

So consider switching to the supported way of recording a JMeter test which is using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or alternatively [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium)